# Why are gradients disconnected

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Consider the following code

```
@tf.function
def get_derivatives(function_to_diff,X):
  f                        = function_to_diff(X)
  ## Derivatives
  W                        = X[:,0]
  Z                        = X[:,1]
  V                        = X[:,2]
  df_dW                    = tf.gradients(f, X[:,0])
  return df_dW
```

I wanted `get_derivatives` to return the partial derivative of `function_to_diff` with respect to the first element of `X`.

However, when I run

```
def test_function(X):
  return tf.pow(X[:,0],2) * X[:,1] * X[:,2]

get_derivatives(test_function,X)
```

I get `None`.

If I use `unconnected_gradients='zero'` for `tf.graidents`, I'd get zeros. In other words, the gradients are disconnected.

Questions

1. Why are the gradients disconnected?
2. How can I get the derivative with respect to the first element of `X`, i.e. how can I restore the connection? I know that if I wrote

```
def test_function(x,y,z)
  return tf.pow(x,2) * y * z

@tf.function
def get_derivatives(function_to_diff,x,y,z):
  f                        = function_to_diff(x,y,z)
  df_dW                    = tf.gradients(f, x)
  return df_dW
```

This could fix the problem. What if my function can only take in one argument, i.e. what if my function looks like `test_function(X)`? For example, `test_function` could be a trained neural network that takes in only one argument.